# How to filter eureka registration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I want to know if there is a way to filter the registration in eureka according to the URL.
For exemple Prohibit localhost instances.
and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you can use the `preferredNetworks` property on Eureka Client, here's a YAML configuration sample:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      preferredNetworks:
        - 192.168
        - 10.0
```

Instead of configuring it on `application.yml` add this configuration to the `bootstrap.yml` file.

You can read more on the [official documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#ignore-network-interfaces).

Comment: Why not? What happens?

Comment: i added it but the instance is registring

Comment: spring:
  application:
    name: eureka
  main: 
    logStartupInfo: true
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  jackson: 
    time-zone: Europe/Paris
    locale: fr_FR
  profiles:
    active: local
  cloud:
     inetutils:
        preferredNetworks:
        - 1.1

Comment: It's really hard to read this unformatted yaml, maybe you can add it to your question using coding format then I can take a look?

Comment: @ericdupont I've edited my answer.
1. Move the configuration to the eureka-client instead of the eureka-server
2. Move the configuration from the `application.yml` to `bootstrap.yml`

Comment: Thank u marco but i need to do this filtering in the server side

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible to achieve.

Comment: I doubt it would work as the client registration relies on the default Netflix eureka-server exposed APIs.